# Scrapy date capture with regular expression

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I have a working regular expression that is parsing a date below:

```
(?:(September|April|June|November) +(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30), *((?:19|20)\d\d))|(?:(January|March|May|July|August|October|December) +(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]), *((?:19|20)\d\d))|(?:February +(?:(?:(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]), *((?:19|20)\d\d))|(?:(29), *((?:(?:19|20)(?:04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96))|2000))))
```

It's parsing the following string:

```
The owners of this address received a permit on Wednesday, July 31, 2014
```

The output of the item in scrapy is:

```
[u'June', u'31', u'2014', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
```

I would like the scrapy item to be:

```
[u'June 31, 2014']
```

Here is my scrapy code:

```
date_scrape = response.css('#ctl00_MasterDiv > div.Divwidth100 td.content_panel_middle > div > p:contains("The owners of this address") > b ::text')

permit_date = date_scrape.re(r'(?:(September|April|June|November) +(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30), *((?:19|20)\d\d))|(?:(January|March|May|July|August|October|December) +(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]), *((?:19|20)\d\d))|(?:February +(?:(?:(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]), *((?:19|20)\d\d))|(?:(29), *((?:(?:19|20)(?:04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96))|2000))))')
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Note - I've tried to add ^ and $ to the expression and I cannot seem to figure it out.  I've tested several possible uses of ^ and $ in regex101 and they all fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
s='The owners of this address received a permit on Wednesday, July 31, 2014'

words = (re.findall(r'(\w+ \d+, \d+)',s))
print words
```

result:

```
['July 31, 2014']
```

Comment: I definitely wasted WAY to much time trying to figure this out.  I saw this solution in other posts, just did not try it.  Thought is was too "simple".  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution if you don't want to dive into the wonderful world of regular expressions.

Use [`dateutil.parser.parse()`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) with `fuzzy=True`. Demo from `scrapy shell`:

```
$ scrapy shell index.html
>>> text = response.xpath('//body/b/text()').extract()[0]
>>> text
u'The owners of this address received a permit on Wednesday, July 31, 2014'

>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse(text, fuzzy=True)
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 31, 0, 0)
```

where `index.html` contains test html data:

```
<body>
    <b>The owners of this address received a permit on Wednesday, July 31, 2014</b>
</body>
```